# how to avoid error "no such file" and upgrade code

Tags: python, json, pandas, path

I try to do this:

```
jsons = [json.load(open(f'this_folder/{folder}/data.json')) for folder in os.listdir('this_ folder')]
```

But not all folders in this_folder contain data.json, and I get error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'this_folder/3634575b59e/data.json'

How to avoid or to ignore this message?
Thanks!!!

Comment: There's nothing related to `pandas` in this question. Why the tag then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `try...except` notation like so:

```
jsons = []
for folder in os.listdir('this_ folder'):
    try:
        jsons.append(json.load(open(f'this_folder/{folder}/data.json'))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

But I really suggest closing files after opening them:

```
jsons = []
for folder in os.listdir('this_ folder'):
    try:
        json_file = open(f'this_folder/{folder}/data.json')
        jsons.append(json.load(json_file)
        json_file.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

Comment: Closing the file is a good idea, but I would use a `with` statement for that. `with open(f'this_folder/{folder}/data.json') as json_file:`. Then closing the file will happen automatically.

Comment: yeah, you're right... you can use `with` statement as well

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a try catch block:

```
jsons = []
for folder in os.listdir('this_ folder'):
    try:
        jsons.append(json.load(open(f'this_folder/{folder}/data.json'))
    except:
        #Do nothing
```

Sorry this is not a one liner.

Comment: Python doesn't have the keyword `catch`. You probably mean `try.. except`

Answer (score 0):

As Anwarvic answer pointed out, a try-except statement is what's to be used here. But you should also close your file, for obvious reasons. You can do that by using the following piece of code:

```
jsons = []
for folder in os.listdir('this_ folder'):
try:
    with open(f'this_folder/{folder}/data.json') as json_file:jsons.append(json.load(json_file))
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass
```